# bash inset additional header and data

Tags: bash, date, header

I have circa 400 CSV files will a large amount of data in them in the following format:

```
As at Date,3/12/2014
Header1,Header2,Header3...
Data1,Data2,Data3...
```

I'm wanting to add a new column (with a header) at the end of the row with the headers and the date shown in the first row on each line there data exit. An example of this would be:

```
As at Date,3/12/2014
Header1,Header2,Header3,Date
Data1,Data2,Data3,3/12/2014
Data4,Data5,Data6,3/12/2014
...
...
```

I know I can grab the details from the first row with:

```
head -q -n 1 *.csv
```

And I know that I can use sed to inset a header into the CSV file but I'm just not too sure how to combine this all together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this

```
awk '
    BEGIN   {FS = OFS = ","} 
    NR == 1 {d = $2} 
    NR == 2 {$(NF+1) = "Date"} 
    NR > 2  {$(NF+1) = d} 
    {print}
' file
```

which can be "one-liner"ed to

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR==1{d=$2};NR==2{$(NF+1)="Date"};NR>2{$(NF+1)=d};1' file
```

If you want just bash, use

```
{ 
    IFS=, read -r asat date; echo "$asat,$date"
    IFS= read -r line; echo "$line,Date"
    while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line,$date"; done
} < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Other awk solution:

```
awk -F, '{
   if (FNR==1) {
       mydate=$2
       print
     } else {
       print $0 "," mydate
     }
   } ' file.csv
```